# How can I get a uitableViewCell by indexPath?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsindexpath

How can I get a `UITableViewCell` by `indexPath`? Like this:

I use the `UIActionSheet`, when I click confirm `UIButton` I want to change the cell text.

The nowIndex I define as a property

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSInteger section =  [nowIndex section];
        NSInteger row = [nowIndex row];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";

        if (section == 0)
        {
            if (row == 0)
            {

            }
            else if (row == 1)
            {
                UILabel *content = (UILabel *)[[(UITableView *)[actionSheet ] cellForRowAtIndexPath:nowIndex] viewWithTag:contentTag];
                content.text = [formatter stringFromDate:checkInDate.date];
            }
            else if (row == 2)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 118):

```
[(UITableViewCell *)[(UITableView *)self cellForRowAtIndexPath:nowIndex]
```

will give you uitableviewcell. But I am not sure what exactly you are asking for! Because you have this code and still you asking how to get uitableviewcell. Some more information will help to answer you :)

**ADD:** Here is an alternate syntax that achieves the same thing without the cast.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nowIndex];
```

Comment: *Technically* you want to call that on whatever the `dataSource` property of your tableView is set to, but usually that is `self`.

Answer (score 27):

**Here is a code to get custom cell from index path**

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
 YourCell *cell = (YourCell *)[tblRegister cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

**For Swift**

```
let indexpath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)
let currentCell = tblTest.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexpath) as! CellTest
```

**For Swift 4 (for collectionview)**

```
let indexpath = NSIndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
let cell = self.colVw!.cellForItem(at: indexpath as IndexPath) as? ColViewCell
```

Comment: In the case of having two custom cell and I need to know which type of cell are returned on this index path. What would be the best approach to get the type?

Answer (score 26):

Finally, I get the cell using the following code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[(UITableView *)self.view cellForRowAtIndexPath:nowIndex];
```

Because the class is extended `UITableViewController:`

```
@interface SearchHotelViewController : UITableViewController
```

So, the `self` is "SearchHotelViewController".

Comment: Naming a class (..)View is confusing if it is a subclass of UIViewController.

Answer (score 13):

For **Swift 4**

```
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following code to get last cell.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath];
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not quite sure what your problem is, but you need to specify the parameter name like so.

```
-(void) changeCellText:(NSIndexPath *) nowIndex{
    UILabel *content = (UILabel *)[[(UITableViewCell *)[(UITableView *)self cellForRowAtIndexPath:nowIndex] contentView] viewWithTag:contentTag];
    content.text = [formatter stringFromDate:checkInDate.date];
}
```

Comment: hi david
i rewrite the question ,can you see it again

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3**

```
let indexpath = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexpath as IndexPath)!
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift**

```
let indexpath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? <UITableViewCell or CustomCell> {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```